# Итератор для массива на jQuery

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript, массивы, итераторы

Имеется функция, в которой при нажатии enter, значения из input попадают в массив, необходимо сделать так, чтобы при каждом нажатии стрелки вверх в input'е показывалось следующее значение массива. Реализовано должно быть как в консоли cmd или bash (при нажатии стрелок показывает более старые и более новые введенные команды). Как реализовать?

```
function arr() {
    var comm_arr = [""];
    start = comm_arr[0];
    $("#input_command").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var js = $('#input_command').val();
            comm_arr.push(js);
        }
    });
    $("#input_command").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Потестировать можно тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wnNaw/1/), код :

```
var arr = [15,58,20,65,84,2,33,48];
var i = 0;
var res = $('#res').text(arr[i]);

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    var cKey = e.which;
    if(cKey == 38 && i < arr.length - 1){
        i++;        
    } else if(cKey == 40 && i) {
        i--;
    }
    res.text(arr[i]);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне граммотно запихнуть это в код, чтобы выводилось через  $('#input_command').val();

Comment: @hesusmordino, например, [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wnNaw/7/)

Comment: Уже реализовал, причем именно так) Спасибо!